# GoogleAnalyticsのイベントタグを事後集計できるか？

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

GTMを使用して、GAを導入しています。
過去にさかのぼって、サイトのイベントクリックを測定したいのですが、可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Googleアナリティクスに限らず、どのようなアクセス解析ツールを使ったとしても、データが送信されていないものについてはどうすることもできません。
事前に「何を計測するべきか」をきっちり決めておく必要があります。